# Under which user context do SQL agent jobs (Transact-SQL script type) run?

Tags: sql-server, sql-job

I notice that all except "Transact-SQL script" type job steps run under context of the "SQL server agent service" account.

Do "Transact-SQL script" type job steps run in the context of "SQL server agent service" account or the "job owner" account or the account belonging to the person who created the job?

Comment: Anything in the SQL Server Agent runs under the SQL Server Agent Service Account, *unless* specified otherwise. In SSMS, for example, you can specify a different user in the Advanced pane of the Job Step Properties.

Comment: I think it also depends on whether the user is sysadmin or not.

Answer (score -1):

You can query system view **sys.dm_server_services** for service accounts.

Under normal conditions, while [SQL Server installation](http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-2019/stand-alone-sql-server-2019-installation-steps.aspx) on Service Configuration step, setup administrators define the service accounts for the related instance

Comment: Do Transact-SQL script type jobs run in context of SQL server agent service or the job owner or the person who created the job?

Comment: They are executed under SQL Server Agent account. You can test it by launching SQL Profiler and you will see the user name executing the job in the list